# How to query to get all users based on a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given:

```
Room (id, updated_at)
RoomMember (room_id, user_id)
User (id)
```

In rails how can I get all users that belong to **all rooms** that were last updated_at in the past 24 hours?

Thanks

Comment: With a distinct return of users

Answer (score 2):

```
User.select('distinct users.*').joins(:rooms).where('rooms.updated_at > ?', 1.day.ago)
```

Comment: that returns the user multiple times, is there a way to get unique?

Comment: `User.distinct("users.id").joins(:rooms).where('rooms.updated_at > ?', 1.day.ago)` should do it

Comment: oops.. sorry.. missed abt the duplicates.. updated the answer to select distinct records

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your models are as follows:

```
class User
  has_many :room_members
  has_many :rooms, :through => :room_members
end

class RoomMember
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room
  has_many :room_members
  has_many :users, :through => :room_members
end
```

You can use the following:

```
User.all(:select => "DISTINCT users.*",
   :joins => :rooms, :conditions => ["rooms.updated_at >=", 1.day.ago])
```

Comment: Thanks but that errors with: ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): join